# Display a message if SQL query is empty using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to check the date in a sql table between two dates. I am trying to display a message if query result is empty. Below is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="result" id="result" name="result">
    <?php echo $head1; ?> <?php echo $out; ?> <?php echo $head2; ?> 
</div>  

<div class="result" id="result1" name="result1">
    <?php echo $out1; ?>
</div>
```

PHP code:

```
if ($_POST['result_options'] == 'Data_Between_Dates'){  
    $startdate = $_POST['start_date'];
    $enddate = $_POST['end_date'];

    $sql ="Select date,select_bank,entry_type,income_cat,expense_cat,amount,expense_cat_sub 
           from wp_formdata 
           Where date BETWEEN  '$startdate' AND '$enddate' 
           order by date";

    $result = $conn -> query($sql);

    if($result>=1){
        $out = "";

        while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()){
            $out .= "<tr><td>".$row["date"]."</td><td>".$row["select_bank"]."</td><td>".$row["entry_type"]."</td><td>".$row["income_cat"]."</td><td>".$row["expense_cat"]."</td><td>".$row["expense_cat_sub"]."</td><td>".$row["amount"]."</td></tr>";
        }
    }    
    else {
        $out1 = "No Result Found";
    }
}
```

I am able to get the non empty date but somehow the `$out1 = "No Result Found";` is not working. Any suggestions here ?

Comment: You can get the number of results via `num_rows`, obviously if the result is 0, you have no results

Comment: Beware about sql-injection in your code...

Comment: Please use Prepared Statements

Comment: Thanks All. will change the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `$result->num_rows` to check if the query returned any records. It returns the number of rows.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $out = "";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $out .= "<tr><td>" . $row["date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["select_bank"] . "</td><td>" . $row["entry_type"] . "</td><td>" . $row["income_cat"] . "</td><td>" . $row["expense_cat"] . "</td><td>" . $row["expense_cat_sub"] . "</td><td>" . $row["amount"] . "</td></tr>";

    }
} else {

    $out1 = "No Result Found";

}
```